# Хранение связей с иерархическими структурами

Tags: mysql, база-данных, nested-sets

Нужен совет.

Есть таблица - иерархический справочник подразделений (nested set). 
id - идентификатор
parent_id - идентификатор родителя
right_key - правый ключ
left_key - левый ключ
level - уровень вложенности

Есть таблица пользователей.
id - идентификатор и т.д.
каждый пользователь может быть владельцем различных узлов или целых нод в таблице подразделений

Нужен совет, как оптимально хранить связь пользователь-нода, чтобы можно было получать список всех подразделений, владельцем которых является пользователь.

Пока только в голову приходит хранить связь 
id пользователя -> id ноды
получать список правых и левых ключей, потом уже в приложении в цикле формировать фильтр:

```
   ...
   OR (node.left_key >= user_node.left_key AND node.right_key <= user_node.right_key)
   и так много раз
```

но это мне кажется не очень оптимальным.

Может кинете ссылок на готовые примеры хранения таких связей?

БД mysql

Comment: *потом уже в приложении в цикле формировать фильтр* А вот это - зачем? Если у Вас уже nested set - создайте на сервере пакет хранимых процедур, выполняющих стандартные операции (в данном конкретном случае - получение всех потомков узла), да и используйте их. Зачем клиента да сетку лишним хламом грузить?

Comment: нет проблем с получением дочерних нод. проблема хранения связи пользователь нода, чтобы можно было потом получать список сущностей, связанных с нодами, принадлежащими конкретному пользователю

Comment: А что, рекурсивного WITH в MySQL нет?

Comment: нет))) это не оракл. Точнее "оракл", но не тот

Comment: есть такая интересная ссылка https://habrahabr.ru/post/193166/

Comment: само дерево сформировано, ссылка не о том

Comment: @DmitryKozlov Ну вот постгрес тоже не "оракл", причем "совсем не оракл". Но тем не менее все есть. Потому и спросил.

Comment: @Dmitry Да даже нерекурсивного - и то нет... вообще никакого нет. Пока. В восьмёрке ожидается, в документации описывается...

Comment: @Dmitry к сожалению не свободен в выборе субд